# Variable comes up as a string; TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'

Tags: python, string, integer

When trying to run this code, it seems to insist that variable x is a string, even after double checking that it is an integer and converting it to one.

```
import time
x = 0

while True:
    print("")
    x = input("Please give a value for X.")
    try:
        int(x)
    except:
        print("")
        print("Sorry, please use an integer and try again!")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        int(x)
        break

abs(x)
```

As mentioned in the title, the error I get in response is this:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'
```

This also occurs for other basic operands. Why is it detecting the variable as a string and how do I fix it?

Comment: assign it to a variable when converting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X variable wasn't updated when you converted it to int. It should be `x = int(x)`.

```
import time
x = 0

while True:
    print("")
    x = input("Please give a value for X.")
    try:
        x = int(x)
    except:
        print("")
        print("Sorry, please use an integer and try again!")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        x = int(x)
        break

print(abs(x))
```

Comment: Ah, that makes a bit of sense. I tried the code and it fixed the TypeError, but now abs() doesn't seem to have any effect on the variable if it's negative.

Comment: Well, abs() does have an effect, but its returned value is never printed. I've just edited the post to fix this problem.

Comment: You actually posted the comment right as I realized another problem I was facing; I simply wasn't updating the variable again. Thanks for taking the time to break this down with me. I'll have to keep in mind for the future that operands don't automatically take effect on the variable, even if it's being done alone.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
abs(int(x))
```

To convert x to integer again

Comment: Hm, alright. But what about for arithmetic operands, such as x*2? And isn't it already an integer by the time it reaches line 17?

Answer (score 0):

The function int() take an argument and if possible, convert it to an int. it returns the converted argument, but does not modify it. So, you can use it as follow examples:

```py
i=int("123")
i=int(12.5)

s="123"
i=int(s)

line = input("Please give a value for X.")
i=int(line)
```